# .bat git pull hangs with PM2 but runs fine when manually run

Tags: git, batch-file, cmd, pm2

I have an auto update script that runs on a server every night that just trashes any modifications, pulls new updates and then restarts the node server. This was working fine until recently where run through PM2 cron jobs or through `pm2 restart/start` it will just hang when it gets to the `git pull` command. But if i run the .bat manually it works perfectly.

The .bat:

```
call pm2 stop server

call git clean -df

call git checkout -- .

call git pull

call npm install

call pm2 start server
```

And the PM2 eco system:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'server',
    script: 'src/app.js',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'jackman_db_autoupdate',
    script: 'autoupdate.js',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: false,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    cron_restart: "1 0 * * *"
  }]
};
```

Comment: Why are you using the `Call` command? _Are `pm2`, `git` and `npm` all batch/cmd scripts?_

Comment: How exactly is the script run on the server, ans how do you manually run it? (please [edit] the question and put the information there...)